# Resizing UIImage from rectangle to square without distortion

Tags: ios, swift, image-resizing

I want to make a function that resize an image from rectangle to square without distorsion.

This is my code :
I have an error (Expression does not conform to type"$T4") for that line : if (UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(aSelector: scaleTransform))

```
func squareImageFromImage(image:UIImage, newSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    var scaleTransform :CGAffineTransform
    var  origin : CGPoint
    var scaleRatio: CGFloat

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
        scaleRatio = newSize / image.size.height
        scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);

        origin = CGPointMake(-(image.size.width - image.size.height) / 2.0, 0)
    } else {
        scaleRatio = newSize / image.size.width
        scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);

        origin = CGPointMake(0, -(image.size.height - image.size.width) / 2.0)
    }

    var size: CGSize  = CGSizeMake(newSize, newSize)

    if (UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(aSelector: scaleTransform)) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)

    } else {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    }

    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, scaleTransform)

    image.drawAtPoint(origin)

    var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code also work for Swift 2.3 and 3.0

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(#selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale))
```

Answer (score 0):

A selector is described in Swift with a `String`.

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(aSelector: "scaleTransform")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `Objective-C` code, I have a following check if `mainScreen` responds to `scale` selector:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)];
```

Transforming this into **Swift** looks like this:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("scale"))
```

So I think the problematic part of your code should look like this:

```
if (UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("scale"))) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
}
```

Hope that helps!