# How to resize and reshape UIImage without causing any distortion?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, resize

I am using the clearbit api to get and display company logos in my app. This works great except that all of the logos are different size, and I want them all to be displayed as a square.

Does anybody know how to take a rectangular image and add extra pixels to it of a given color until it becomes square with the logo at the center?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832150/resizing-uiimage-from-rectangle-to-square-without-distortion) seemed to answer it, but it is outdated. I also thought that the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506565/resize-uiimages-canvas-and-fill-the-empty-place-with-color) would work, but the code didn't work. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Determine the scale factor that preserves aspect ratio
        let widthRatio = targetSize.width / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        
        let scaleFactor = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        
        // Compute the new image size that preserves aspect ratio
        let scaledImageSize = CGSize(
            width: size.width * scaleFactor,
            height: size.height * scaleFactor
        )

        // Draw and return the resized UIImage
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(
            size: scaledImageSize
        )

        let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(
                origin: .zero, 
                size: scaledImageSize
            ))
        }
        
        return scaledImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `    func drawImageOnCanvas(_ useImage: UIImage, canvasColor: UIColor ) -> UIImage {

   ```
   let length = max(useImage.size.width, useImage.size.height)
   let canvasSize = CGSize.init(width: length, height: length)
   let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize)
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

   // fill the entire image
   canvasColor.setFill()
   UIRectFill(rect)

   // calculate a Rect the size of the image to draw, centered in the canvas rect
   let centeredImageRect = CGRect(x: (canvasSize.width - useImage.size.width) / 2,
                                  y: (canvasSize.height - useImage.size.height) / 2,
                                  width: useImage.size.width,
                                  height: useImage.size.height)

   // get a drawing context
   let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   // "cut" a transparent rectanlge in the middle of the "canvas" image
   context?.clear(centeredImageRect)

   // draw the image into that rect
   useImage.draw(in: centeredImageRect)

   // get the new "image in the center of a canvas image"
   let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

   return image!
   ```

   }`
2. `   func imageWithColor(color : UIColor,oriImage:UIImage) -> UIImage{

   ```
   let length = max(oriImage.size.width, oriImage.size.height)
   let size = CGSize.init(width: length, height: length)
   let imgView = UIImageView.init(image: oriImage)
   imgView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
   imgView.backgroundColor = color
   imgView.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: length, height: length)
   print("\(size.width)" + "\(size.height)")

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
   guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{
       print("context get Error")
       return oriImage
   }
   imgView.layer.render(in:context)
   let desImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

   return desImg ?? oriImage
   ```

   }`

Comment: I just gave these both a try, but neither solution worked for some reason. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I guess you did not set UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit to your UIImageView, can you gave me more info?